# How can a parent send a message to n children with one pipe?

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, fork

What I'm trying to do is to send a message to each child and than see which one prints it out first. I've tried using one pipe so my code looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    int pfd[2];

    if(pipe(pfd)<0){
        perror("pfd error");
        exit(1);
    }

    int n=5;

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        pid_t pid=fork();
        if(pid<0){
            perror("fork error\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if(pid==0){
            close(pfd[1]);
            char ms[256];
            int h;
            read(pfd[0],&h,sizeof(int));
            read(pfd[0],ms,h*sizeof(char));
            cout<<i<<"_"<<ms<<endl;
            close(pfd[0]);
            exit(0);
        }
        if(pid>0){
            close(pfd[0]);
        }
    }

    int j=1;
    char uzenet[256];
    strcpy(uzenet,"start");
    int ho=strlen(uzenet);
    while(j<=n){
        if(write(pfd[1],&ho,sizeof(int))==-1){
            perror("write error");
            exit(1);
        }
        if(write(pfd[1],uzenet,ho*sizeof(char))==-1){
            perror("write error");
            exit(1);
        }
        j++;
    }
    close(pfd[1]);
    while(wait(NULL)>0){};
    exit(0);
}
```

And it prints out this:

```
2_
1_start
4_
3_
5_
```

But what I want is this:

```
2_start
1_start
4_start
3_start
5_start
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't with only one pipe!

Data read from a pipe is consumed, that means that once something is read from a pipe it will never be available, it disappears from the pipe (think about water and pipe, drinking consumes the water).

If you share the reading part of a pipe in between different processes, then they will be concurrent. That means that you can't have any guaranty on who will read some data. The system is able to choose any reader he wants among all readers that request reading at some point. In the worst case, one process would read everything. In general, you will have a kind of random choice. It is not random, but almost impossible to control (and surely a bad idea to try). At least don't think about replicate N times the message on the writing part, and hope that the N readers will be able to read one copy each.

pipes cannot be used to broadcast something. If you want it, implement your own broadcasting system.

---ADD---

Also don't forget that pipe data have no semantic, there is no concept of messages inside, if you need it you'll have to implement some protocol to simulate it. I mean that you can't flood the pipe with liters and drink drops, or the converse...

Comment: Well, interestingly enough only one child process seems to consume the `"start"` part. But of course your answer is correct.

Comment: So I should create n pipes for n children then send "start" to all of them?